# What does "{{ form|crispy}}" mean?

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am doing exercises in a `django` tutorials book, and when using `crispy` forms the line

```
{{ form|crispy}}
```

is used. The author does not explain it as I assume it must be commonly understood. I have never seen this notation used (I am new to this) and I would like to understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in documentation https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms that "|crispy" filter will render div based forms, can be combined with another method such as_table, as_ul and as_p. The main goal of this method to do not repeat your form.

Comment: Thank you! I was not having any luck finding that in the documentation. Is the "|" (bitwise operator?) just a part of the name of the filter, or does it translate to other commands. The particular usage of that character is what is stumping me. In other words, is it just a character, or is it a command or shorthand for something else? Thanks!

Comment: In a django template the pipe "|" character definitely does not mean the 'bitwise OR' operator. It indicates that you want to send the results of the left hand side (before the pipe character) to the filter defined on the right side. The filter will modify the value in some way. It called built in filter reference in django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference.

Comment: Many thanks! Completely cleared everything up for me, at least regarding pipe.

Comment: My pleasure, sir :)